# Updating forms values is not working yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have default forms which were generated by crud. I need to update message column.

My View site/index.php

```
<div class="notifications-events-index">

<?= Html::encode($this->title) ?>



<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summary' => false,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'date_at',
        'type',
        'event_id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'Message',
            'filter' => true,
            'format' => 'raw',

            'value' => function ($model) {
                $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'action' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/update', 'id' => $model->id])
                ]);
                return $this->render('_msg', [
                    'model' => $model,
                    'form' => $form,
                ]);
            },
        ]
    ],
]); ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My updateAction in SiteController

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => NotificationsEvents::find()->orderBy('date_at'),
    ]);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->save(false);
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

findModel is working. When I save my updating values they are not updating. Any ideas?

Comment: why $model->save(false);?

Comment: to ignore validation

Comment: Don't start ActiveForm widget in closure and end it in parent grid view - that's completely wrong

Comment: Are you sure you enter in the if condition for saving?

Comment: If you want to edit a column inside a gridview, I suggest you to use Kartik EditableColumn

Comment: i guess i know what you trying to do. You have to take a look over to load multiple method and see how they works. Also, like is mentioned by @Bizley, it is wrong way to use activeform inside the gridview. You have to use AJAX. and create your own methods to handle ajax request at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reason to not updating the records:

1. Check validation ,  there may be a chance some validation is applying.
2. Check you attribute available in **safe**  in your model .
3. Debug Your POST data. There may be a chance your post data is not posted .

If you still not able to solve it please post you model as well .